# After Cythonization Schemas are Gone in FastAPI Docs and Calls are not Working

Tags: python, post, cython, fastapi, cythonize

I cythonized my project folder and removed all files except .so and .sh files. I was able to deploy it and it was up and running, but in docs schema information is gone and I'm not able to send information from docs into database as I had done previously. I got 500 error when I attempted to make POST calls with the data that was working before cythonization. What might be the reason?

[image]

My cythonization code:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import shutil
extensions = []

for root, directory, files in os.walk('./api'):
    if 'alembic' not in root:
        for file in files: 
            if file.endswith('.py') and\
                'keycloak' not in file:
                module_name = os.path.join(root[2:], file)
                package_name = root[2:].replace('/', '.')
                print(package_name, ' ', module_name)
                extensions.append(Extension(package_name, [module_name]))

setup(
    name='Indexer',
    cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext},
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions,
    compiler_directives={
        'c_string_type': 'str',
        'c_string_encoding': 'utf8',
        'language_level': 3})
)

def delete_files():
    for root, directory, files in os.walk('./'):
        if 'alembic' not in root:
            for file in files: 
                if not file.endswith('.so') and\
                not file.endswith('.sh') :
                    module_name = os.path.join(root, file)
                    os.remove(module_name)

def delete_directories():
    for root, directory, files in os.walk('./'):
        if root != './':
            shutil.rmtree(root)

def move_files():
    for root, directory, files in os.walk('./api'):
        if 'alembic' not in root:
            for file in files: 
                if file.endswith('.so'):
                    module_name = os.path.join(root, file)
                    shutil.move(module_name, file)

move_files()
delete_files()
delete_directories()
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure without an [mre]. It seems likely that you need some introspection feature that Cython doesn't provide, or that the library does tests for "exact Python function" that Cython can't possibly meet. You might try turning on the `binding` compiler directive, which makes Cython functions a little more introspectable

Comment: I added 'binding': True, no luck. :(